# @ConfigurationPropertie not working Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-config

Here is my application.properies...

```
extract.magoo=tony
```

I am trying to read this in.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("extract")
public class ApplicationProperties {
    ...
    String magoo;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;   

    @PostConstruct
    public void validate() {
         System.out.println("******* magoo=" + magoo);
         System.out.println("**** " + env.getProperty("extract.magoo"));
    }
```

Will output:

```
******* magoo=null
**** null
**** tony
```

So the property magoo on the class is never injected.  But I can get the value from the Environment bean.  So this means it is reading application.properties.

Note in a Configuration class, I have added the @EnableConfigurationProperties annotation.

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ApplicationProperties.class)
public class ExtractToolConfiguration {
...
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable `@ConfigurationProperties` by adding `@EnableConfigurationProperties` on a  `@Configuration` class. Then

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="extract")
public class ApplicationProperties {
  String magoo;
  public void setMagoo(String magoo){
    this.magoo = magoo;
  }
}
```

You also need the setter.

Comment: Thanks I was missing the setter. Is there anyway I can get that free without having to type it out.